# How to make a <span> inside an <a> display in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k4u8U/)  in order to create a tag cloud, the tags are `<a>`'s and inside it I  insert a span with the tag's count inside it.

I want them to be always together but in some cases the line breaks although I have the "display: inline" set for the `<a>` just in case, still it does not work.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I have updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `a` and `span` elements are inline by default. Your problem is that inline elements are word-wrapped, and that works per-word, not per-element.

Either disable word wrapping with `white-space: nowrap` or make the outer element `display: inline-block` to make it wrap as a complete element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `white-space:nowrap` to the a element.

See the modified example http://jsfiddle.net/k4u8U/4/

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `white-space:nowrap;` to your  css. That tells the browser to disable any text wrapping inside the element.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4u8U/3/

Answer (score 0):

Either add `display:inline-block;` or `white-space:nowrap;` to your CSS for `a` tag.

Here are the 2 updated jsfiddles:
with `display:inline-block;`
http://jsfiddle.net/k4u8U/5/

with `white-space:nowrap;`
http://jsfiddle.net/k4u8U/6/